# My flash alerts disappear sometimes but not all the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My flash messages sometimes disappear as expected and sometimes do not.

Here's an example of the flash message working (controller)

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, alert: "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Email or password is invalid"
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

Here's an example of the flash alert not disappearing

```
  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, alert: "Logged out!"
  end
```

Here's the jQuery function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#notice_wrapper').fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $(this).remove();
    })
  }, 3500);
});
```

Here's the html/css/erb for the wrapper

```
<% if notice %>
    <div id="notice_wrapper" style="position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 999; background: rgba(135, 216, 211, 0.85);">
      <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    </div>  
  <% elsif alert%>
    <div id="notice_wrapper" style="padding: 2.5rem 0; text-align: center; margin: 0; font-size: 1.25rem; font-weight: 700; color: white; letter-spacing: 1px;">
      <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Why would this work for the first example and not the second.

Comment: is your flash message wrapped in a container with the same id(`notice_wrapper`) ?

Comment: Yes, i added the html/css to my post

Comment: have you tried putting a `debugger` inside the function that `setTimeout` executes ?. It could be that the js code is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll assume you have `protect_from_forgery` turned on in your application_controller.

I had a similar issue where flash was working fine on `#create` and `#update` but not on `#destroy`. It had to do with the `protect_from_forgery` which clears the flash_hash if the request is unverified like when there is a missing token on a non GET request.

You can solve this in 2 ways:

1. Sending your delete request through a form so Rails will inject the correct token. My mistake was using a `link_to` tag which generates `<a>` instead of a `button_to` tag which generates a form.
2. Adding a condition to the `protect_from_forgery` so it won’t clear the flash_hash for example `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }`. I saw this solution [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108236/discussion-between-7urkm3n-and-rafael-laurindo).

I found [this](https://nvisium.com/blog/2014/09/10/understanding-protectfromforgery.html) article to be helpful for more info on `protect_from_forgery`.

Comment: I don't have anything for protect_from_forgery currently configured, I wonder if this is enabled by default? I went ahead and set it up as `button_to` and it worked for me.

Comment: It should be enabled by default in your `application_controller.rb` file.

Comment: This is my current application_controller.rb file `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    helper_method :current_user
    
    def current_user

      
      if session[:user_id]
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
      else
        @current_user = nil
        
      end
    end
  end` Im not sure why I dont have that line in there but when I try to add it I get an undefined error method